# jquery animate callback : complete/done or promise().done() starts before animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-animate

I am a new in jquery so can you help me why this command doesnt animate?
Animation not working, and "letter" returns in previous position without animation, so callback fires before animation, and if i am not using done or complete - animation works. Even if i use .animation.promise().done(xxxx) - xxx starts before animation.
Main question is how make .css("position","static") after animation?

```
    $("#DestinationLetter0").animate({
      top: 203,
      left: 80
    }, { 
      duration: 4000,
      done: (function(w1, w2) {
        $("#DestinationLetter0").css(w1, w2)
      })("position", "static")
    });
```

Example code provided below

````
<html>
   <head>
       <title>AJAX</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#DestinationLetter0").css({position:"absolute"}).animate({top:200,left:200},9000);
               $("#DestinationLetter0").click(function(){$("#DestinationLetter0").animate({
                    top: 50,
                    left: 50
                }, { 
                    duration: 4000,
                    done: (function(w1, w2) {
                        $("#DestinationLetter0").css(w1, w2)
                        })("position", "static")
                    })});
            }) 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><p id="in3"><span id="DestinationLetter0">A</p></div>        
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Did you saw my answer @Anton Kotikov ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me if its what you need

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#DestinationLetter0").css({position:"absolute"}).animate({top:200,left:200},9000);
 $("#DestinationLetter0").click(function(){
   $(this).animate({
      top: 50,
      left: 50}, {
  }, 4000).promise().done(function () {
       $(this).css("position", "static");
  });
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p id="in3"><span id="DestinationLetter0">A</p></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i understood that IIFE not acceptable in this case. But my problem a little bit complicated, - i must send a lot of parameters to callback and i have a lot of animations to be done one after each other.